# Extend Laravels Router class (4.1)

Tags: php, laravel, extending

I would like to extend Laravels Router class (Illuminate\Routing\Router) to add a method I need a lot in my application.

But sadly I can't get this to work. I already extended other classes successfully so I really have no idea where my wrong thinking comes from.

Anyway, right into the code:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router as IlluminateRouter;

class Router extends IlluminateRouter
{
    public function test()
    {
        $route = $this->getCurrentRoute();
        return $route->getParameter('test');
    }    
}
```

So as you see I want to get the parameter set by {test} in routes.php with a simple call like:

Router::test();

Not sure how to go on now. Tried to bind it to the IOC-Container within my ServiceProvider in register() and boot() but I got no luck.

Whatever I try I get either a constructor error or something else.

All solutions I found are too old and the API has changed since then.

Please help me!

edit:
I already tried binding my own Router within register() and boot() (as said above) but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use MyApp\Extensions\Router;
class MyAppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['router'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Router(new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher); 
        }
        // Other bindings ...
    }
}
```

When I try to use my Router now I have the problem that it needs an Dispatcher.

So I have to do:

```
$router = new Router(new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher); // Else I get an exception :(
```

Also it simply does nothing, if I call:

```
$router->test();
```

:(

And if I call 
    dd($router->test());

I get NULL

Answer (score 2):

Look at: `app/config/app.php` and in the aliases array. You will see `Route` is an alias for the illuminate router via a facade class.

If you look at the facade class in `Support/Facades/Route.php` of illuminate source, you will see that it uses `$app['router']`.

Unlike a lot of service providers in laravel, the router is hard coded and cannot be swapped out without a lot of work rewiring laravel or editing the vendor source (both are not a good idea). You can see its hardcoded by going to `Illuminate / Foundation / Application.php` and searching for `RoutingServiceProvider`.

However, there's no reason i can think of that would stop you overriding the router class in a service provider. So if you create a service provider for your custom router, which binds to `$app['router']`, that should replace the default router with your own router.

I wouldn't expect any issues to arise from this method, as the providers should be loaded before any routing is done. So overriding the router, should happen before laravel starts to use the router class, but i've not this before, so be prepared for a bit of debugging if it doesn't work straight away.

Comment: Hey. First of all: Thanks! But I tried that already, couldn't get it to work. Can you provide some source for this? I can do it with other classes just fine but my code wouldn't work. See my edit in the question.

Comment: Can't really give you a step-by-step to get it working, there's just too much involved and its such an obscure request, it's something i'd have to code myself before i was sure on the exact implementation. For a start though, passing in the dispatcher to the constructor won't work properly anyway. If you just open the serviceprovider constructor you will see it requires the Application instance only (which is provided by the IoC so you dont even have to pass that in). I've not tested it, but try looking at this, it may help you https://github.com/pixeloution/laravel-custom-router

Comment: Uhm, the app-version is for 4.0 and it doesn't work that way anymore *confused*

Comment: You see the same problem here: https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router/issues/16 You just can't give it an Instance ob Application :(

Answer (score 0):

So I was asking in the official Laravel IRC and it seems like you simply can't extend Router in 4.1 anymore. At least that's all I got as a response in a pretty long dialogue.

It worked in Laravel 4.0, but now it doesn't. Oh well, maybe it will work in 4.2 again.
Other packages suffer from this as well: https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router/issues/16

Anyway, personally I'll stick with my extended Request then. It's not that much of a difference, just that Router would've been more dynamic and better fitting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 4.2, and the router is really hard coded into the Application, but I extended it this way:

Edit bootstrap/start.php, change Illuminate\Foundation\Application for YourNamespace\Application.

Create a class named YourNamespace\Application and extend \Illuminate\Foundation\Application.

```
class Application extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application {
    /**
     * Register the routing service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerRoutingProvider()
    {
        $this->register(new RoutingServiceProvider($this));
    }
}
```

Create a class named YourNamespace\RoutingServiceProvider and extend \Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.

```
class RoutingServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider {

    protected function registerRouter()
    {
        $this->app['router'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            $router = new Router($app['events'], $app);

            // If the current application environment is "testing", we will disable the
            // routing filters, since they can be tested independently of the routes
            // and just get in the way of our typical controller testing concerns.
            if ($app['env'] == 'testing')
            {
                $router->disableFilters();
            }

            return $router;
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, create YourNamespace\Router extending \Illuminate\Routing\Router and you're done.

NOTE: Although you're not changing the name of the class, like Router and RoutingServiceProvider, it will work because of the namespace resolution that will point it to YourNamespace\Router and so on.